# Trying to create update profile page in PHP PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create an update profile page in PHP. But, I keep running into an error. When I submit the form to update the profile, there are four fields. Username, email, firstname, and lastname. Say I want to change only the first name of the user, when I submit the form, it gives me an error telling me the username/email/lastname is taken because that was already auto-filled in.

[Here is my update profile form, the fields contain user information pulled from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdSVb.png)

Here is my update profile code that goes along with the form

```
    // Queries
if (isset($_POST['userprofileupdate'])) {
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name_1']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name_2']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email_1']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);

    // Check if Email exists
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email ');
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $Count = $stmt->rowCount();

    // Check if username exists
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username ');
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $Count1 = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($Count < 1) {
        if ($Count1 < 1) {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET username=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, email=? WHERE id=?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam('ssssi', $username, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
            unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
            unset($_SESSION['role']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            session_destroy();

            header('Location: /panel/login?profile_changed');
        } else {
            header('Location: /panel/profile?username_taken');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: /panel/profile?email_taken');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Please remove that function. It should not be in your code

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: Instead of doing SELECT to check for duplicates, create a UNIQUE constraint on the database column

Answer (score 1):

You can use either positional placeholders

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, email=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$firstname, $lastname, $email, $id]);
```

Or named placeholders

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username=:username, firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, 
        email=:email WHERE id=:id";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    'firstname' =>$firstname, 
    'lastname' => $lastname, 
    'email' =>$email, 
    'id' => $id,
]);
```

or please read fully this article for complete understand
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update